# Python one-line boolean

Tags: python, pandas

Given `df`

```
    col1
0    -12
1    -64
2     24
3      2
4      6
5     75
6      3
7     10
8     42
9     15
10    14
```

I'm trying to make something like:

`df_new`

```
    col1
0      0
1      0
2      1
3      0
4      0
5      1
6      0
7      0
8      1
9      0
10     0
```

Where, if the number is greater than 15, then it is 1 and 0 otherwise. I tried to do it this way:

```
df_new = [1 for x in df if (x<15) else 0]
```

But it gives a syntax error.

Comment: You're using Pandas, right? You might want to add the [tag:pandas] tag. Pandas-specific solutions should be simpler and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the condition to the entire df all at once:

```
new_df = df > 15
```

The result will be a boolean, but will behave as zeros and ones in all the ways that you care about.

As for your original expression, a ternary operator has the form `[a if cond else b for x in iterable]` while a filter looks like `[a for x in iterable if cond]`. Notice where the `if` goes in both cases.

Comment: The df's were an example. When applying it to the real database, it doesn't work. df_new gives me the same data as df, without booleans.

Comment: @Strovic. Please show me a snippet where that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the booleans to ints like this:

```
df_new = (df>15).astype(int)
```

Comment: I'd use `df.gt(15).astype(int)` to make the chaining easier~

Answer (score 1):

While others are right about using the features specific to dataframes, your understanding of list comprehension syntax is only a little bit off.

```
[1 if x < 15 else 0 for x in df]
```

Or if parentheses help you to see what's going on:

```
[(1 if x < 15 else 0) for x in df]
```

Comment: This would be true if that were a plain list, but pandas DataFrames don't respond that way in a list comprehension.  `for x in df` results in the columns, not the rows.

Comment: Agreed. I felt it was a good opportunity to correct the misunderstanding of list comprehension and conditional expression syntax.

Comment: 1) You could make it valid by using df['col1'] instead of df, and 2) conditional expression should be `1 if x > 15 else 0`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `where` function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([-12,-64,24,2,6,75,3,10,42,15,14])
df=np.where(df>15,1,0)
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
```

**Syntax :** `numpy.where(condition[, x, y])`